# Move samba and ldap config to new machine

Tags: ldap, server-message-block

I'm not advanced administrator so this may be n00b question but I'll be grateful for help.

I have following problem: I have to move my server (ubuntu server) from old machine to new. I have samba & ldap on old server, so I've copied the configuration files from the old machine to new machine, made `smbldap-populate`, and when I use `smbldap-userlist` on the new machine it lists all users from the old machine. But when I try to log in as any of these users, or show its id (`id username`) I get `no such user` error.

What more I have to do to use these accounts on the new machnie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely you haven't copied the PAM configuration that actually tells the system to use LDAP to look up users.  Take a look in `/etc/pam.d` on the old system.  Depending on the version, you're looking at `system-auth` and possibly a few others.

If you have copied these configs, you should be looking at various logs in `/var/log` for any errors related to PAM.  If you do find some and you're not sure how to proceed, go ahead and update your original question with those log entries.

Comment: You are almost right. I had different hostname in pam.d configuration (until I'll replace servers I'm using different host name for new machine). Thank you for hint!